# How to link classes in different packages (on different pages)?

Tags: object-oriented, uml, packages, class-diagram

Extending [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960432/uml-how-to-manage-big-class-diagrams/960445#960445) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960432/uml-how-to-manage-big-class-diagrams), I have broken down a large system into a few classes per package.

Each package is now shown in a different page for readability, but now how do I show the relationship of two classes in separate packages (separate printed pages)?

**An example for clarification:**

[image: E has an association with A but are in separate packages]

E has an association with A but are in separate packages (which means they are on different pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to show a subset of Package2 on the diagram for Package1. In this case, you would show Package2 and ClassE, but not at full detail. Don't include any private or protected members, and consider not even showing public members for ClassE on the diagram for Package1. Depending on how they are structured, include a note or reference to the Package2 diagram for easy access via a link or a document ID reference.